# How to save video thumbnail permanently in video file

Tags: php, html

This is how we set video thumbnail in html.

```
<video controls poster="/images/w3html5.gif">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

But i want to save this thumbnail for video permanently in video file so that i do not need to set it using html poster attribute.

is it possible to save this thumbnail in video file?

If possible please help me out. Thanks.

Comment: you mean, without using video editing software?

Comment: yes, i want to do it using code or some third party tool like 'FFMPEG'

Comment: No, it is not possible if you are doing it with the html player. Rather if you use any jquery player plugin the thumbnail will be automatically fetched from the video. To fetch the thumbnail use the below command in `$output = shell_exec("ffmpeg -i input.flv -ss 00:00:14.435 -vframes 1 out.png");`